# Blazor.net Unwanted button clicks on input key presses

Tags: c#, .net, button, input, blazor

I'm new to Blazor and have just started evaluating it's suitability for our companies future needs.

I have set up a page and created a MVVM class. I have tested and debugged the MVVM class in a console application and it works fine.

This is my page:

```
enter code here@page "/signIn"
@using System.Runtime.CompilerServices
@using ViewModels.Models.SignIn

<h1>Sign In</h1>
<table width="200" border="1">
    <tbody>
         <tr>
             <td>Account</td>
             <td>
                 <input @bind-value="@Model.CarrierId" @bind-value:event="oninput"/>
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Username</td>
             <td>
                  <input autofocus @bind-value="@Model.UserName" @bind-value:event="oninput"/>
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Password</td>
             <td>
                  <input type="password" @bind-value="@Model.Password" @bind-value:event="oninput">
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
              <td>"@Model.Clicked"</td>
              <td>
                  <button disabled="@Model.DisableSignIn" @onclick="@Model.ExecuteSignIn()">Login</button>
              </td>
          </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>


@code {
         SignInViewModel Model;

         protected override void OnInitialized()
         {
              base.OnInitialized();
              Model = new SignInViewModel( StateHasChanged );
         }
     }
```

Everything works OK except that whenever I press a key in any one of the input elements the event bound to the button fires also. So I get a button event on every key press.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, MVVM is the wrong pattern here. MVVM works best with Desktop UI technologies. WPF and UWP are in particular designed for it. But Blazor is a Web UI, wich seems to work best with the MVC pattern - or at least it is a extremely common pattern.

Comment: Try `@onclick="Model.ExecuteSignIn"`. One `@`, no `()`

Comment: With or without the brackets did exactly the same thing

Comment: When you call them 'brackets' I'm still not sure you took this literally.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the button event has to be structured like:
     @onclick="(e => Model.ExecuteSignIn())"

Comment: No, it shouldn't be used that way.

Comment: After upgrading to the .NET CORE 3.1 Version @onclick="Model.ExecuteSignIn" now works.

Comment: You must have been on a very old version. Please corect this answer, someone will copy/paste it at some time.

Comment: No, actually it was the latest .NET STANDARD version.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to the .NET CORE 3.1 Version @onclick="Model.ExecuteSignIn" now works.